# Ubuntu 16.04 browser won't connect to proxy server

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, lenovo, proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and access internet behind the college's proxy server which requires authentication credentials. The problem is, at certain places in my college I'm able to access internet, while at the same time at my college hostel, the browser displays "Unable to connect to proxy server." message. Both the hostel and the college campus are supplied with the same wifi network. Also my another laptop having ubuntu 14.04, works completely fine at both places. the laptop I'm having trouble with, is lenovo ideapad 300 dual booted with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04; windows works perfectly well.

PS: I've posted this question using lenovo (booted on ubuntu os), and it's working fine right now in class.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem (from my point of view) might be **Proxy Setting**. It might have set to manual to make it work in College. 
If your Hostel's Router is configured to some static IP and Port No. you will need to know it and configure it manually. This worked in my case as in College it required to proxy settings to be manually configured and at home none proxy settings worked just perfect.

To Change Proxy settings goto :-
**System Settings -> Network -> Network proxy -> Change Method -> Apply System Wide**

[It Settings should be **None** *or* **Automatic** for Hostel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl9bi.png)

You Also Might need to change Proxy Settings in your browser (firefox)
*goto:-*

**edit->Preferences->Advanced-> Network -> (Connection)Settings -> Auto Detect Proxy**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on the wi-fi connection of my college.
But instead of 'auto-detect proxy' , the option 'No proxy' worked for me.
My system is Windows10 and xubuntu 16.04 dual-booted on Lenovo Ideapad Y500.